# ListView - zoomed out and transparent elements

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtdeclarative

I have a scrollable and flickable `ListView` with 5+ elements and I'd like to have the elements which are shown at both ends zoomed out, transparent and slightly moved so the whole list becomes rounded up, sort of getting the shape of a wheel.

I think the two images describe it best:

That's what I have:

[image: What I have]

And that's what I want:

[image: What I want]

Since I'm also targeting devices without GL - although deprecated - I'd prefer a QtQuick 1.x version, however I'm happy with all I can get :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As stated in the answer, `PathView` is the best choice. If you still want to go with the `ListView`, take a look to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078608/2538363).  Although related to a different topic, some parts of the solution applies to your case.

Answer (score 3):

The `ListView` is not exactly meant to do that.
Have a look at the [`PathView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html).
There are a lot of examples from the documentation, maybe you'll find there something very similar to what you want to do.

Otherwise you should put a `MouseArea` in your delegate and react to the `entered` and `exited` signals. Do not forget to update the size of the delegate accordingly to the size of its content if needed, otherwise the items will overlap each other.

That said, I'd maybe use the `PathView` to do that.