# Hiding an item outside viewport of a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I've been learning QtQuick for about a week and I'm facing a weird behaviour on what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to make a vertical `ListView` with a Keyboard navigation so that when I press UP or DOWN, the items move up or down and if an item goes in or out of the "viewport", its `opacity` property will change smoothly to `0` or `1`.

Here is my current QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    width:200
    height:400
    ListView {
        property int activePosition:1
        property int itemDisplayed:3
        width:parent.width-50
        height:parent.height-50
        anchors.centerIn:parent
        model:10
        snapMode:ListView.SnapToItem
        focus:true
        cacheBuffer:2000
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log(count+' != '+contentItem.children.length+' ???')
        }
        Keys.onPressed: {
            var i = 0
            console.log('pos='+activePosition)
            console.log(count+' != '+contentItem.children.length+' ???')
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Up) {
                if (activePosition == 1 && currentIndex > 0) {
                    i = currentIndex+itemDisplayed-1
                    if (i < contentItem.children.length - 2/* why -2 instead of -1 ??? */) {
                        console.log('out='+i)
                        contentItem.children[i].state = 'out'
                    }
                }
                activePosition = activePosition > 1 ? activePosition - 1 : activePosition
            }
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Down) {
                if (activePosition == itemDisplayed && currentIndex < contentItem.children.length - 2) {
                    i = currentIndex-itemDisplayed+1
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        console.log('out='+i)
                        contentItem.children[i].state = 'out'
                    }
                }
                activePosition = activePosition < itemDisplayed ? activePosition + 1 : activePosition
            }
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id:rect
            state:index < ListView.view.itemDisplayed ? 'in' : 'out'
            opacity:1.0
            width:ListView.view.width
            height:ListView.view.height/ListView.view.itemDisplayed
            border.color:'white'
            border.width:1
            color:activeFocus ? 'red': 'gray'
            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus) {
                    state = 'in'
                    console.log('in='+index)
                }
            }
            states: [
                State { name:'in'; PropertyChanges { target:rect; opacity:1.0 } },
                State { name:'out'; PropertyChanges { target:rect; opacity:0.0 } }
            ]
            transitions: [
                Transition {
                    to:'in'
                    NumberAnimation { property:'opacity'; duration:250 }
                },
                Transition {
                    to:'out'
                    NumberAnimation { property:'opacity'; duration:250 }
                }
            ]
            Text {
                text:index
                anchors.centerIn:parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First question : model=10, why `model.count` is not equal to `contentItem.children.length`? `onCompleted` gives 5 vs 11 and during navigation 10 vs 11

Second question: If I press UP or DOWN, it works fine until I reach index=4, why?

As I'm a beginner on QtQuick so maybe it's not the right approach. I tried to use the `visible` property but every item has `visible = true` even if they are outside. I tried also `indexAt()` with no success.

Any help would be great :-)

Comment: `contentItem.children.length` is 11 because you have 10 `Rectangle` and the `ListView` itself. `ListView` is also counted. The problem with your code is related to `currentIndex`, which is not always the index of the element where you are entered. Log the value to fix your code. I think you don't need `activePosition`. You should be able to control the state of your items just with `currentIndex`.

Comment: I have a better understanding of the problem now :-) That's why everything was fine until index=4 because contentItem.children[4] is actually the index of the ListView. And your are absolutely right about the activePosition which is not necessary beacause now I can handle this part using the itemAt method. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem :) If you fix the code, please, answer your own question and mark the solution as the right one ;) Happy coding!

Comment: It should be noted (even if it should not effect your code much) that the delegates in a `ListView` are created *on demand*, i.e. once a delegate goes out of the viewport it is destroyed whereas when it comes in it has just been created. You can test such a behaviour by using `Component.onCompleted`/`Component.onDestruction` inside the delegate itself. See for instance [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27201691/2538363) and the nice effect obtained using these handlers.

Comment: Indeed, nice effect with shorter code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know better about the `ListView` behavior. My previous code can be fixed by removing the `Keys.onPressed` event which is no longer useful, and by using the `itemAt()` method directly into the `onActiveFocusChanged` handler.