# Ownership of retrieved model data in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

There are multiple ways of retrieving data from, for example a `ListModel` in QML.

- First, there is the view, e.g. `ListView`, that will expose the model data to its delegates. This is solved by the comment of @BaCaRoZzo with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078251/listview-scrolling-animation/27201691#27201691)
- Secondly there is the `get(index)`-method, that will return the item at that index.

I wonder about the lifetime of those data, in the second case.
Who is the `parent` of the retrieved data item? Is it the caller, the callee or null? Who owns and determines the lifetime? QML, C++ or JS?
In the documentation you find the remark:

> **Warning**: The returned object is not guaranteed to remain valid. It should not be used in property bindings

I don't know whether this might imply: "The returned object might be destroyed without further notification"
or rather: "The values of the returned object are not bound to the models values, so they won't update when the models data changes, and lose validity this way"?

Comment: But now, in the second case, where I retrieve the object via the `get(index)`-Method, I am not necessarily inside a view. I might have an Object outside any `View`, totaly unrelated. The view might display the items 10 - 20, while next to the view I have a Text displaying one role of a random - e.g. 200 - element of the ListModel, by retriving the data via `property var myData: listModel.get(200)` and then bind to myData.rolename. This might work well, when I can assume, myData will live, but might not be updated (ok...). It can be bad, if the Model at some point decides to let it go.

Comment: Yeah, I've removed the comment because I thought it was a little bit out of scope with the second part. :) But anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: Since we are talking about a JavaScript object being returned, it is likely reference counted and garbage collected.